# Handling lat/long and mysql spatial points in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, spatial

There have been a decent amount of questions about mysql spatial datatypes, however mine is more specific to how **best** to deal with them within a rails MVC architecture.

I have an input form where an admin user can create a new point of interest, let's say, a restaurant and input some information.  They can also input a human-readable latitude and longitude in decimal format.

However, for distance calculations, etc... I am storing the location data as a spatial point in the database.

My question therefore, is how to best handle this in the MVC architecture in rails?

Here are some ideas I had, but nothing really seems clean:

- Call :after_filter method that takes the new instance of the object and does a raw SQL update that handles the "GeomFromText('POINT(lat long)' ))" goodness.  The issue with this is that "lat/long" would be text fields in my create form, although this disrupts the clean form_for :object architecture that rails provides since lat/long aren't really attributes, they're just there to let a human input values that aren't mysql spatials.
- Maybe creating a trigger in the db to run after a row insert that updates that row?  I have no idea and it doesn't seem like these triggers would have access to the lat/long, unless I stored the lat/long as well as the spatial point, and then created the row in the db with the lat/long decimals, and then ran the trigger after creation to update the spatial.  I guess i could also do that with an after_filter if I added the lat/long columns to the model.

Any other ideas?  I think storing the lat/long is redundant since I'll really be using the spatial point for distance calculations, etc... but it might be necessary if I'm allowing for human editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [the geokit-rails plugin for Rails](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails) which does distance calculations using plain lat/lng columns as floats (and uses the [geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/) gem). However, if you'd like to use your database's geo-spatial abilities, [GeoRuby](http://georuby.rubyforge.org/) supports the basic spatial features like Point or LineString as column types. I hope these help.

Comment: Cool, I had seen geokit, but for some reason had it stuck in my head that I had to store locations as spatials instead of lat/longs.  I'm using ym4r_gm for the display package, which takes lat/long anyways, so these should play nice together.

Comment: yeah, Geokit & ym4r_gm is exactly what I use and it's working ok for the moment. Perhaps it'll evolve as/if I have to scale up.

Comment: i can't seem to find the geokit plugin?  

script/plugin install git://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.git 

is returning "Plugin not found"...?  Is this a git hosting issue maybe?

Comment: Nevermind, I updated rails and tried using an http protocol instead and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with hopeless, geokit is nice, I use it too.

If you want to do it yourself, I would do an after_filter but externalize the update method to a thread. Like that you don't have a slow down while saving but still nice code and timely updated columns.

Triggers are not nice, the database should deliver data but not do logic.